# Would it be possible to remove (or hide) a button through the code?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have been googling this question, but so far nothing found.

Is there some function, that enables me to remove or hide an button (in wpf)?

For example:

A form with 2 buttons on it:

1. On initialize, only button 1 will be visible
2. Click button1, this will make button2 visible
3. Click button2, this will make button1 get removed (or hidden).

Is such a thing possible in c# in WPF?

Comment: This is perfectly possible. Just set the `Visibilty` property to `Collapsed`.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the `Visibility` of the button to `Visibility.Hidden` or `Visibility.Collapsed`?

Comment: Have you allowed Intellisense to help you? In most cases it helps just looking at the member names of the object you want to manipulate, since most members of .NET framework classes have a rather meaningful name.

Comment: I strongly doubt you've actually googled the issue...

Comment: i did google it and did not find, guess i used the wrong search words. thanx for the comments it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and very easy to do, just use the buttons click event handlers to toggle the other buttons `visibility` property.

And one more important thing you have to give a name to your buttons so you can use them from code behind.

[MSDN Visibility Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look at setting it Collapsed on one click and uncollapsed on the other

For Button 1's ClickEvent

```
button2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```